# How to run Laravel schedule command as Cron Job online

Tags: laravel, cron

I’m setting up a Cron Job for my laravel Schedule in CpaneL but it's not working. Please, i need help on how to do schedule:run in cPanel Cron Job.

This is what i have tried in cPanel Cron Job

/usr/local/bin/php7 /home/cattonli/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

php artisan schedule:run works fine offline, but i can't get it to work offline.

Comment: This looks like a very cpanel-specific question, try including some tags to attract the right stackoverflow readers. I would also check if /home/cattonli/public_html/artisan is executable. Finally, you could remove the ">> /dev/null 2>&1" portion and see if you get any cron errors that could help you troubleshoot where the problem is.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try this now. But how do i check if /home/cattonli/public_html/artisan is executable? Sorry, am new to this.

Comment: try `ls -l /home/cattonli/public_html/artisan` and check the file permissions. check http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php to learn more about permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope "cattonli" is the username.
Try Below if it works for you.

If you have created "laravelapp" folder inside project folder try

/usr/local/bin/php7/**bin/php-cli**/home/cattonli/public_html/**{project_folder_name_if_any_or_skip}**/**laravelapp**/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Yes,  "cattonli" is the username.  thanks. I'll try this now. Thank you

Comment: It didn't work. I created a Link called  client/idef  that works online when I run it directly as  https://mysite/client/idef and it ran my command. How do I write the Cron JOB for this link using my path. Thanks